# Virtualenv says "root" instead of the name of virtualenv?

Tags: python, command-line, virtualenv

For a while, I have been using virtualenv's for many python projects. When I tried to activate one of my virtualenv's, I typed:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Which generally does the trick. However, instead of my command prompt saying:

```
(venv)me@example:~/
```

It says:

```
(root)me@example:~/
```

My python version requirement and my packages that I installed on the virtualenv are not recognized. Why does this happen?

Comment: Maybe you used `sudo -i` for root user prompt, and created a venv on the root folder, which is where you are destined after using that comando. Or maybe the name of the venv folder is `root`>

Comment: I didn't use sudo -i and the name of the venv folder is "venv". I just don't know why this is happening, and I can't use any of my venv's without this happening.

Comment: Try uninstalling virtualenv and reinstalling.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
source activate venv
```

(instead of `source venv/bin/activate` or `./venv/bin/activate.sh` etc.)

```
THundtMac$ source activate venv
(venv) THundtMac$ source deactivate
THundtMac$ . ./venv/bin/activate
(root) THundtMac$ source deactivate
THundtMac$
```

I think this has to do with using Anaconda vs the pip-installed version.  (I'm using the conda-installed one now.)

Answer (score 1):

Once in the virtual environment bin folder, typing:
`source ./activate`
instead of:
`source activate`
solved the problem for me.

Please note that the latter command actually activate a "base" environment (called "root" if you use the pip version of `virtualenv`, and "base" if you use the conda version of `virtualenv`), and not the environment you are actually trying to activate