# Why is the prompt of my virtual environment different from its name?

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtualenv

I'm building a Django Project, and I first created a virtual environment.
Before I work on it, I go to the /bin/ of my virtualenv, then I go

> source activate

Usually, it then says:

> (myVirtualEnv)

because that's how I named it. And I can do Python manage.py runserver, and all these sort of things.

But since yesterday, after my`source activate`, it says :

> (base)

...  and the other doesn't work !

I don't understand what happened. Any help ?

Comment: did you download anaconda yesterday?

Comment: A possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44981499/virtualenv-says-root-instead-of-the-name-of-virtualenv). I'm not sure what the problem is, but you could try using Pipenv. It automatically creates and manages a virtualenv for your projects. Just a recommendation.